# Is every metrizable topology induced by a Heine-Borel metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples

A metric space $(X,d)$ has the [Heine-Borel property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem#In_the_theory_of_metric_spaces) if for any subset $A$ of $X$, $A$ is compact if and only it is closed and bounded.  ($\mathbb{R}^n$ is the classic example.)  My question is, for any metrizable topological space $X$, does there exist a metric on $X$ which induces the topology on $X$ and which has the Heine-Borel property?

If not, what is an example of a topological space such that all the metrics which induce the topology fail to have the Heine-Borel property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any metric space with Heine Borel property is sigma compact. An infinite dimensional Banach space is never sigma compact.

Comment: Or any uncountable set with the discrete topology, for the same reason.

Comment: Why does the Heine-Borel property imply sigma-compactness?

Comment: $X=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline {B} (x,n)$ for any fixed point $x$. @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  By the way, does every sigma compact metrizable space have a Heine-Borel metric which induces its topology?

Comment: It must also be locally compact. $\mathbb Q$ is $\sigma$-compact but not locally compact. Maybe a locally compact separable metrizable space has a Heine–Borel metric?

Comment: @bof Does having a Heine-Borel metric imply seperability?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan For metric spaces, Heine–Borel $\implies$ $\sigma$-compact $\implies$ Lindelof $\iff$ separable.

Comment: In my opinion boundedness and Heine -Borel property are poorly defined concepts in a general metric space. This is because any metric $d$ is equivalent to $\frac d {1+d}$ which makes the entire space bounded. @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: @bof I just posted a question about your guess: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3047238/71829