# Is every uniformizable topology induced by a Heine-Borel uniformity?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples, uniform-spaces

This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3046056/71829).  A subset $A$ of a uniform space is said to be bounded if for each entourage $V$, $A$ is a subset of $V^n[F]$ for some natural number $n$ and some finite set $F$.  Just like for metric spaces, a compact subset of a uniform space is always closed and bounded, but the converse need not be true.  A uniformity has the Heine-Borel property if a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Suppose $X$ is a uniformizable topological space, AKA a completely regular topological space.  My question is, is it necessarily the case that the topology on $X$ is induced by some Heine-Borel uniformity?

Now [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3047249/71829) shows that a metrizable topology is induced a metric with the Heine-Borel property if and only if it is locally compact and separable.  But that doesn’t answer this question, because even if we take a topology which isn’t locally compact or isn’t separable, it’s possible that such a topology is induced by a non-metrizable uniformity with the Heine-Borel property.

Comment: It's probably false, but one would need some more theory on the classs of uniform spaces with the HB property to disprove it, I think. Is this class closed under products, uniformly continuous images etc. ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It may be even easier; the proofs that topologies induced by Heine-Borel metrics are locally compact and separable may be able to be modified to show that topologies induced by Heine-Borel uniformities are locally compact and separable.

Comment: I don't think that would hold (separability and local compactness), btu I'm not sure. Just a hunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space $X$ is pseudocompact if any continuous $X\to\mathbb R$ is bounded.
There exist completely regular non-compact pseudocompact spaces $X$ such as the long line ([there are other examples at π-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=completely%20regular%20%2B%20pseudocompact%20%2B%20%7Ecompact)). By pseudocompactness, $X$ is bounded in any continuous pseudometric. By the positive answer to your previous question [Is a set bounded in every metric for a uniformity bounded in the uniformity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051775/is-a-set-bounded-in-every-metric-for-a-uniformity-bounded-in-the-uniformity), noting that the answers also work for pseudometrics in non-metrisable spaces, $X$ is bounded in every uniformity. So $X$ does not admit any Heine-Borel uniformity.